# Golang, appending leaves only last element

Tags: go

Here is example code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Product struct {
    Id       int64
    Title    string
    AttrVals []string
}

type ProductAttrValView struct {
    Product
    Attr string
}

type ProductAttrVal struct {
    Attr    string
    Product int64
    Value   string
}

func main() {
    p := Product{Id: 1, Title: "test", AttrVals: []string{}}
    var prod *Product
    prodViews := []ProductAttrValView{
        ProductAttrValView{ Product: p, Attr: "text1" },
        ProductAttrValView{ Product: p, Attr: "text2" },
        ProductAttrValView{ Product: p, Attr: "text3" },
        ProductAttrValView{ Product: p, Attr: "text4" },
    }

    // collapse join View to Product with Attrs
    for _, pview := range prodViews {
        if prod == nil {
            prod = &pview.Product
            prod.AttrVals = make([]string, 0, len(prodViews))
        }
        if pview.Attr != "" {
            fmt.Printf("appending '%s' to %p\n", pview.Attr, prod) // output for debug
            prod.AttrVals = append(prod.AttrVals, pview.Attr)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", prod) // output for debug

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/949w5tYjcH

Here i have some returned data from DB in `ProductAttrValView` struct and want
put it into `Product` struct and also fill `Product.AttrVals`

It prints:

> &{Id:1 Title:test AttrVals:[text4]}

While i expect this:

> &{Id:1 Title:test AttrVals:[text1 text2 text3 text4]}

So, all text should be appended, but for some reason only the last element stays in `Attrs` slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-using variables in your for-range loop, and each iteration modifies the value of that same variable. You can create a new value each iteration with the trick:

```
pview := pview
```

http://play.golang.org/p/qtJXxdtuq2

You also initialize the slice with a length of 4, but you `append` another value (ignoring the first 4). You likely meant to set the capacity of the slice as opposed to the length:

```
prod.AttrVals = make([]string, 0, len(prodViews))
```

Because the *value* of `prod` is changing each iteration, the code would be a lot less confusing if you specifically initialized the `prod` value, instead of assigning the address of `&pview.Product`

```
prod = &Product{AttrVals: make([]string, 0, len(prodViews))}
```

#### [time line]

1. You create a single product `p`, containing an initialized []string
2. That same `p` is assigned to all `prodViews` that we will iterate over.
3. On the first iteration through the loop, you assign `*prod` to that initial `p` value, then change `AttrVals` to a new `[]string` of length 4. This doesn't alter the original `p`.
4. `pview.Attr` is appended to `prod.AttrVals`, making a it length 5, and creating a new underlying array. This isn't reflected in the values of `p`.
5. On subsequent iterations, `pview` is overwritten with the next value in `prodViews`. This overwrites the value of `prod` too, since it points to the `pview.Product` value. This means that `prod.AttrVals` is now the same one from the original `p`.
6. `pview.Attr` is appended to a slice of length 0, and the underlying array is replaced with more capacity, so `pview.Attr` still isn't contained in the original `p`.
7. `pview` is again overwritten with the next value, which contains original `p` values, setting your `AttrVals` length back to 0 with an empty array.
8. The cycle continues until the final single value is printed.

Comment: Note that the `make([]string, len(attrVals))` creates a slice of four empty strings--Dfr probably wanted `make([]string, 0, len(attrVals))` to set capacity, not len. Also, note that `pview` is a *copy* of a `ProductAttrValView`, and to modify the original, you'd want `for i := range prodViews { pview := &prodViews[i]; ... }`.

Comment: @twotwotwo: good points. The code is awkward, but seemed very contrived so I didn't want to try and read too much into it.

Comment: I not initializing `prod` here because it should be taken from View or at least copied, but i thought here: why do copy if i can reuse already existing one ? Also if you ran play example, you could see that each iteration it appending to the same product and to the slice with the same memory address

Comment: @JimB: `and each iteration modifies the value of that same variable` - please can you specify which variable ? Here i modify only `prod.AttrVals` which is just completely independent from `pview`

Comment: @Dfr: wrote a timeline of what is going on in your code

Comment: @JimB thank you, this is so crafty, but if you say that `prod` is changing: `This overwrites the value of prod too, since it points to the pview.Product` then why `prod` is pointing to the same address in every iteration ?

Comment: @Dfr: `prod` is pointing to the same address in `pview`, but the values are being over-written. Maybe this will explain it better http://play.golang.org/p/u3RGOAZkw9